How to add suffix st or nd or rd depond on number?
How to add suffix like "st", "nd", or "rd" depending on number in JSONata?
I want to achieve something like this:

If number is 1, output "1st"
If number is 2, output "2nd"


You can use conditionals and then string concatenation like shown in the example code below.
$number := 2; // Replace with your number
$lastDigit := $number % 10;
$lastTwoDigits := $number % 100;
(
  ($lastTwoDigits >= 11 and $lastTwoDigits <= 13) ? $number & 'th' : 
  ($lastDigit = 1 ? $number & 'st' : 
  ($lastDigit = 2 ? $number & 'nd' : 
  ($lastDigit = 3 ? $number & 'rd' : $number & 'th')))
)


Why and $lastTwoDigits <= 13 ??

For 11, 12, 13, the output will be 11th, 12th, and 13th respectively, checking two digits not one

and for 14 it would be ?  (In fact the complete check $lastTwoDigits >= 11 and $lastTwoDigits <= 13) ? $number & 'th' seems useless)

Well you are right to some extent

something like: ($number >= 4 ) ? $number & 'th' :    ($lastDigit = 1 ? $number & 'st' :    ($lastDigit = 2 ? $number & 'nd' :    $lastDigit = 3 ? $number & 'rd' : $number & 'th'))    but than can even be optimized.

You can declare this custom function on top of your JSONata expression and use it like so:
(
  $toOrdinalNumber := function($number) {
    (
      $suffixes := ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"];
      /* for numbers > 100 */
      $remainder1 := $number % 100;
      /* for numbers < 100 */
      $remainder2 := $remainder1 % 10;
      /* special cases for 11, 12, 13 */
      $suffix1 := $remainder1 >= 11 and $remainder1 <= 13 ? "th";
      $suffix2 := $suffixes[$remainder2];
      /* 1. If suffix1 isn't null, return it.
        2. If suffix2 isn't null, return it instead.
        3. If both possible suffixes aren't available,
        safely assume the ordinal number ends with 'th'. */
      $finalSuffix := $exists($suffix1)
        ? $suffix1
        : $exists($suffix2)
          ? $suffix2
          : $suffixes[0];
      /* convert number to string and attach suffix */
      $string($number) & $finalSuffix
    )
  };
  /* call the custom function anywhere in your expression below */
  {
    '1': $toOrdinalNumber(1), /* 1st */
    '51': $toOrdinalNumber(51), /* 51st */
    '83': $toOrdinalNumber(83), /* 83rd */
    '111': $toOrdinalNumber(111), /* 111th */
    '123': $toOrdinalNumber(123), /* 123rd */
    '145': $toOrdinalNumber(145) /* 145th */
  }
)

Playground link: https://jsonatastudio.com/playground/4e1ae089
